# como puedo usar una variable booleana recorriendo un objeto en vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

quisiera poder recorrer el campo fecha de mi arreglo creditos donde si creditos.fecha == ayer (variable que me trae el día anterior) entonces color sea true y si no es esa fecha que sea false.

```
data:{
   ayer: '',
   color: false
}

     getCreditos: function (){
        axios.get(urlCreditos).then(response => {
          this.creditos = response.data;
        });
      }


<td v-if="credito.fecha === ayer" :class="{'text-success' : color}">@{{fechas(credito.fecha).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}}</td>
            <td v-else="credito.fecha === ayer" :class="{'text-danger' : color}">@{{fechas(credito.fecha).format('DD/MM/YYYY')}}</td>
```

hasta el momento lo tengo como se muestra en v-if y v-else y funciona, pero quisiera no usar esas 2 lineas en el blade para poder hacer que sea esa parte desde vuejs, como podría hacerle?

PD. así como está me funciona perfectamente, pero lo que quiero es poder manejarlo todo desde mi app.js que es donde tengo todo mi codigo de vue.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear la seccion mounted(){} para que se ejecute una ves cargada la pagina

```
mounted():{
axios.get(urlCreditos).then(response => {
          this.creditos = response.data;
          const className = (credito.fecha === ayer)? "text-success" : "text-danger"

        });
}
```